# postgresql: reader process consuming high cpu

Tags: linux, postgresql, operating-system, admin, database-administration

I am getting high cpu at postgres server. The consuming process is named as reader process. I would like to know what is this process and why it is consuming high CPU.

postgres 20602     1 99 12:09 ?        10:59:22 postgres: reader process

CPU usage

20602 postgres  20   0  612820  17592   2392 S **370.6%**  0.1 685:28.81 postgres

Please guide and provide the resolution.

Comment: You must be using an extension that starts this "reader process". Care to tell us more about your setup and workload?

Answer (score 0):

Your server is hacked, it's a miner program.

Comment: can you elaborate on that? what is the resolution that you're proposing in your answer